# org.jooq.exception.DetachedException: Cannot execute query. No Connection configured when deploy to standalone Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jooq, tomcat8

When I run the app from IntelliJ IDEA all works fine, but when I deploy EXACTLY THE SAME war-file to standalone Tomcat I get the following exception:

org.jooq.exception.DetachedException: Cannot execute query. No Connection configured

It is quite odd because it looks like jOOQ simple cannot connect to DB, but from IDE all works fine.

I tried to change DB url in different ways but no success.

Please advice where to look to prevent the error: tomcat, jooq or something else?

Versions are: Java 8, Tomcat 8.08, jOOQ 3.3.2

**UPD:** Got the solution: Since I do all the 'connection' stuff (creating, opening, closing etc) by hand It is required to load JDBC driver by hand as well: `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");`

It is very odd, but running from IntelliJ IDEA loads the driver 'behind the scenes' - that was the main issue.

Comment: How do you configure the `DataSource` that you provide jOOQ with?

Comment: I just create connection like this `DriverManager.getConnection(JdbcUrl, User, Password);` JdbcUrl, User, Password are values from properties file.

Comment: Also I logged url, user, passwd and they are correct.

Comment: ... you'll need to provide some more information. There are many things that can go wrong on the way, it's hard to guess where the issue is. Try supplying all the configurations, code, etc. that is relevant to this Stack Overflow question

Comment: Good news! Note: You can answer your own question here on Stack Overflow. It will be more useful for a future visitor of this question.